# In Stargate Atlantis, when Atlantis leaves Lantea wouldn't they have a different point of origin?

Tags: stargate

As the question states, in the SGA episode: "[First Strike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Strike_%28Stargate_Atlantis%29)" Atlantis moves from Lantea to another planet.

I can accept that McKay could get the Atlantis gate back onto the Stargate grid, but wouldn't that mean that Atlantis would get a **new point of origin**?

Comment: What indications are there that it didn't get a new point of origin?

Answer (score 8):

It is canon that the gate system has an automated update program so while technically the symbol on their gate remained the same it used their new location as the point of orgin

Comment: ok so unless im getting confused wouldnt the actual address change also? considering that the first 6symbols denote co-ords?

Comment: @Lou Atlantis might have a fixed address just like the Destiny. Both are technically ships and both can be dialed long distance (read: from another galaxy). So they need to be able to cope with changing positions. I'm not sure if it was addressed in the show how that works exactly. But it might just work like our internet. You access a fixed domain which you perceive as an address but it's technically just an alias that can point dynamically to changing IP addresses.

Comment: This is just plain wrong. The gate does get a new point of origin; http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/New_Lantea

Answer (score 7):

### They *did* get a new point of origin (PoO)...

The [Stargate Wikia](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Point_of_origin) lists [***New Lantea***](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/New_Lantea) as having a different point of origin symbol to [(Old) Lantea](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Lantea).

**Lantea PoO symbol;**

### [image: PoO Symbol Lantea]

**New Lantea PoO symbol**

[image: PoO Symbol New Lantea]

We also know that by the point that Atlantis moves, Carter and McCabe are well aware of how to reprogramme a gate and create a new point of origin, as evidenced by their upcoming plan to retask dozens of gates to make a [trans-galactic bridge](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/McKay/Carter_Intergalactic_Gate_Bridge).

Comment: There is also the way Daniel used the gate on Apohis' ship with Earth's point of origin to access the Alpha Site and escape before they were destroyed - once they knew what the origin point is (and like you said Carter/McKay were in the midst of retasking a whole bunch of them), I doubt that much reprogramming would need to be done

Comment: @Robotnik - Yes, by this point they've got a laptop/DHD interface working.

Comment: Your acronym for "Point of Origin" is incorrect. It should be PoO.

Comment: Once they reach Earth however, maybe this is a new question, would not the same situation as the Russia get begin with Earth being the origin point for both gates? Or would the Atlantian gate be fancy enough to still work with its own?

Comment: I think the Pegasus and Milky Way networks were not, by default, compatible. When they built the bridge station, travelers had to physically exit one network, and then continue dialing the next network, as the forwarding program wouldn't connect the two networks.

Comment: @ench - I seem to recall that the Midway station was a safety 'air-gap' rather than because the networks were inherently incompatible. Possibly worthy of its own question though

Comment: @Valorum You may be right. All the references to incompatibility seem to be about the dialing macro, not the network itself.